Atributos en las relaciones, ¿Cuando y por qué causas? Modelo EER
Estoy preparando unos apuntes para impartir una clase y no quisiera decir algo inapropiado. Estoy buscando ayuda para confirmar el conocimiento actual o cambiarlo por ser erróneo.
Cuando estudié el tema de los atributos en la relaciones del EER, allá por 2003 me explicaron que
las relaciones pueden llevar atributos en las siguientes situaciones:

Por ejemplo si la relación varía un dato con el paso del tiempo. SE agrega fecha como atributo en la relación.
Si un valor de un atributo cambia según la relación. Por ejemplo Medico atiende paciente.  La relación atiende llevaría los atributos de diagnóstico, fecha de ingreso, síntomas, etc., que cambiarían cada vez que el médico atiende al paciente.

¿Puede alguien confirmarme que estos motivos son exactos?
¿Hay más motivos para agregar atributos a una relación?, ¿Cuáles?
Entiendo que sólo las relaciones N:M llevan atributos. ¿es correcto?
